React Native sudden error messages props.pointerEvents is deprecated Expo Go
I’m working on a React Native project and suddenly I’m getting a series of error messages that weren’t there before. It seems like there’s an issue with the Metro bundler or some configuration in the project. I haven’t made any changes to the codebase that would trigger these errors. All of a sudden my project doesnt work anymore after installing the latest version of React Native, i cant use the App on the Phone with Expo Go anymore and i get messages like "WARN  props.pointerEvents is deprecated. Use style.pointerEvents" which werent there before, but it works in the web ...
So i wanted to ask if someone else encountered the same issue ?
I was trying deleting it completly running other versions etc
